# How can I add elements to a list using a for loop?

Tags: python

I'm using `open(filename)` to open a file that contains the numbers 73, 85, 66, 0, and 99.

I'm adding each number to a list named `values`. Now I want to get the mean of all of the numbers. I'm trying to sum the values using a variable named `sum` and then print the sum.

```
values = []
for i in values:
    sum = sum + i
print sum:
```

This code is giving me the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'`

Comment: Do you know how to read the numbers from the file into values? You mention that in your question, but you don't show how you're doing that in your code. Also, as Pikamander2 mentions, you shouldn't have a `:` at the end of your `print` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `sum` as a variable name, which you haven't initialised. But `sum` is the name of a built-in function, so you shouldn't use it as a variable name because it can lead to problems like this. :) Your code is telling Python to add the integers in `values` to a function, so it complains. But this works:

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

total = 0
for i in values:
    total = total + i
print total
```

**output**

```
10
```

FWIW, the above code would work if we used `sum` instead of `total` to store the current accumulated sum because it gets initialised before the start of the loop. But that's not a good idea, since it means you can't access the proper `sum()` function if you need it later. Also, it's a bit confusing to people reading your code.

---

Or you could just use the `sum()` function, since it's designed to add together the contents of an iterable:

```
print sum(values)
```

**output**

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling `sum = sum + i`, you haven't given `sum` a value yet. You can't add 1 to an undefined variable.

Declare `sum = 0` before your code block and it should fix the problem.

Also, there shouldn't be a colon after your print statement. Was that a typo, or is that actually in your code?